# How to make make a script to convert audio streams and copy all video streams and subtitles?

Tags: windows-10, audio, video, ffmpeg

I have a bunch of videos of which I want to convert all the audio streams from FLAC to Opus while copying all the video streams and subtitles. I was experimenting with this command for one video but it doesn't apply the bitrate I specified:

`ffmpeg -i "input.mkv" -map 0:v -map 0:s -c copy -map 0:a -c:a libopus -b:a 128k test.mkv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `libopus` encoder, by default, uses variable bit rate mode. If you need a constant bit rate mode, set VBR to off i.e.

```
... -c:a libopus -b:a 128k -vbr 0 ...
```

Comment: I added -vbr 0 but it still won't change the bitrate to the specified one. ```ffmpeg -i "input.mkv" -map 0:v -map 0:s -c copy -map 0:a -c:a libopus -b:a 128k -vbr 0 test.mkv```

Comment: There can be some imprecision. Try some neighbouring values if you need to see an exact specific value in the output.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong but it's always giving me 5XX kb/s according to the MediaInfo.

Comment: I took some screenshots too: https://imgur.com/a/3u21GLy

Comment: The metadata of the source contains that number, which ffmpeg has copied over. And Mediainfo is reading from that.